# @RequestPart annotation not showing required symbol

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-3.0

I am using the below annotation to show multipart file attribute on swagger-ui, which is working fine.
But issue starts where i need to show the required(*) symbol for file attribute on swagger-ui.

Here is how I am using @RequestPart annotation.

**@RequestPart(value = "file", required=true) final Multipart file**

But required property is not being applied, please suggest, how to add required symbol on any attribute using @RequestPart annotation.

Comment: I just use "@RequestPart MultipartFile file" as a parameter in the post method and the required symbol is shown in swagger-ui.

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet, and also which version of swagger you are using ?

Comment: Here is my controller method: public String getTextFromMultipartFile(@RequestPart MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(required = false) List<Integer> pageNumbers)

Comment: I use swagger2 version 3.0.0

Comment: I'm having the same issue; tried different ways. but required flag is coming as false in swager json

Comment: Its a known issue in swagger:v3, Below link could be helpful for you.

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1954